# Vue.js: Have multiple different colored rows in table in v-for

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm having trouble to set multiple colors to my table rows in a v-for.
I'm working on a simple soccer app which shall show recent match results of a certain team.
My problem here is: I want to change the background color of the element based on the result of the match:

- win -> green
- lose -> red
- draw -> grey

On my page I have a button which calls the function "story". The function "story" simply pushes all matches of a team from the "matches" array into the "history" array. After this is done I check whether the team won, lost or had a draw. I then change the "theme" variable to what the result is.
In my HTML I now set the class dynamically to what the "theme" variable is.
Problem: All table rows are now set to the color based on the last result that was pushed into the "history" array.
I searched desperately for a solution but couldn't find what I need.
Here my code:

```
<template>
<table id="table2">
 <button class="button" @click="story"></button>
 <tr :class="theme" v-for="match in history" :key="match">
   <td>{{ match.team1 }}</td>
   <td>{{ match.goals1 }}:{{ match.goals2 }}</td>
   <td>{{ match.team2 }}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</template>
```

```
<script>
data() {
 return {
 matches: [
  {
   team1: Real Madrid,
   team2: FC Barcelona,
   goals1: 1,
   goals2: 1 
  },
   team1: Atletico Madrid,
   team2: FC Barcelona,
   goals1: 1,
   goals2: 2 
  }
 ],
 history: [],
 theme: ""
 }
},
methods: {
  story: function() {
  this.history = []; //empty past inserts
  team = "FC Barcelona";
  for (let i = 0; i < this.matches.length; i++) {
   if (this.matches[i].team1 == team || this.matches[i].team2 == team) {
    this.history.push(this.matches[i]); //paste match in history
    //now I want to check if my team won, lost or had a draw
    if (this.matches[i].team1 == team) {
     if (this.matches[i].goals1 == this.matches[i].goals2)
      theme = "draw";
     else if (this.matches[i].goals1 < this.matches[i].goals2)
      this.theme = "lose";
     else if (this.matches[i].goals1 > this.matches[i].goals2)
      theme = "win";
     }

     if (this.matches[i].team2 == team) {
      if (this.matches[i].goals1 == this.matches[i].goals2)
       theme = "draw";
      else if (this.matches[i].goals1 > this.matches[i].goals2)
       theme = "lose";
      else if (this.matches[i].goals1 < this.matches[i].goals2)
       theme = "win";
     }
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<style>
 tr.lose {
  background-color: rgb(202, 43, 43);
 }
 tr.win {
  background-color: rgb(53, 86, 230);
 }
 tr.draw {
  background-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Your story function has a typo in it.    `if (this.matches[i].team1 == team || this.matches[i].team2 = team) {` You have a comparison operator `==` and then an assignment operator `=`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a computed property based on `history` and determine the theme inside that.

```
...

data () {
    return {
        history: []
    }
},
computed: {
    themedHistory () {
        this.history.map(item => {
            // determine the theme based on the item
            // const theme = ...

            return {
               ...item,
               theme
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your template

```
<tr :class="match.theme" v-for="match in themedHistory" :key="match.id">
    ...
</tr>
```